# Sql Statements as Data in mySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I have to produce a pretty complex report.   Without a doubt someone will ask me for the individual records that make up the counts, totals etc.

Im new to mySql.  I have tried and found out that I can store Sql statements as data of type Text without any real problems.

Being able to do it, however begs the main question:

Is this a good idea?  Is there anything here that will hit me with a "Got ya!"

(Its always what you don't know that gets you, never what you do know)

The report will return Sales Count: 5

I would Live to store "SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE Producer_ID = 34" so I can quickly get to the 34 records that make up the 5 Sales count

Comment: When you say "Sql statements" are you referring to the actual query or the data set that is returned?  If it is the Query, I think you may want to look into Stored Procedures.

Comment: Are you personally (or your team) putting the statements into the database? Or is there a part of your app which accepts user input and stores those scripts? If it's just you, it's probably ok. But I would never allow any user (even ones you "trust") to have the ability to create SQL statements that get stored anywhere.

Comment: The report will return   Sales Count: 5    I would Live to store  "SELECT * FROM Sales WHERE Producer_ID = 34" so I can quickly get to the 34 records that make up the 5 Sales count.

Comment: im not really sure what you are doing could you tell us, in a step by step fashion, how a user typically interacts with those reports? what's his input and what's his desired output..

Comment: why would you want to store SQL statements inside a DB? you should try to figure out what possible scenarios are needed, hardcode the queries letting only some parameters vary and NEVER expose your query to your end user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing SQL queries as data in a SQL DB is sometimes labelled dynamic SQL queries.  It is prone to injection issues, and should not be undertaken lightly.  I recommend not doing so unless you have a very good reason to do so.

Comment: im curious what would be a valid reason to store queries inside a DB?

Comment: @DanyKhalife remember favorites in phpmyadmin

Comment: @DanyKhalife  I've created applications which utilize a "wizard" which allow a non-SQL layman to input various values which in turn creates custom views of their data. Yes, the final SQL can be derived by the inputted values, however, I stored the SQL statement (actually, several parts of it) to improve performance.

Comment: @mnagel oh yea! of course.. :) i was thinking about something any user would you use, but not from a programmer's perspective :D

Comment: I am actually writing  the report to a Table in Xojo.  If the cell for sales count on January 1 was 34   i would have stored  "SELECT ID FROM Sales WHere sell_date = "2013-01-01" in the cell tag of the result.   Then I can simply pass the SQL statement to a function  ShowCellDetails (SQL)